# sh: command not found when using Snakemake profiles

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to create a new profile for snakemake to easy run workflows on our cluster system. I followed the examples available in the Snakemake-Profiles repo, and have the following directory structure:

```
project/
- my_cluster/
-- config.yaml
-- cluster-submit.py
-- jobscript.sh
- Snakefile
- (other files)
```

Thus, the `my_cluster` directory contains the cluster profile. Excerpt of config.yaml:

```
cluster: "cluster-submit.py {dependencies}"
jobscript: "jobscript.sh"
jobs: 1000
immediate-submit: true
notemp: true
```

If I try to run my workflow as follows:

```
snakemake --profile my_cluster target
```

I get the following error: `sh: command not found: cluster-submit.py`, for each rule snakemake tries to submit. Which may not be super surprising considering the cluster-submit.py script lives in a different directory. I'd have thought that snakemake would handle the paths when using profiles. So am I forgetting something? Did I misconfigure something? The `cluster-submit.py` file has executable permissions and when using absolute paths in my config.yaml this works fine.